# need regular expression to match dynamic url to setup goal in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I need to match complete dynamic URL to set-up as a goal in Google Analytics. I don't know how to do that. I have searched on Google with no luck.

So here is the case.

When pressed **enter** button, the goal URL would be different depending on the product selected.

**Example:**

> http://www.somesite.com/footwear/mens/hiking-boots/atmosphere-boot-p7023.aspx?cl=BLACK
>
> http://www.somesite.com/womens/clothing/waterproof-jackets/canyon-womens-long-jacket-p7372.aspx?cl=KHAKI
>
> http://www.somesite.com/travel/accessories/mosquito-nets/mosquito-net-double-p5549.aspx?cl=WHITE
>
> http://www.somesite.com/ski/accessories/ski-socks-tubes/ski-socks-p2348.aspx?cl=BLACK

If you look closely in the URL, you can see that there are three parts:

> http://www.somesite.com/{ 1st part }/{ 2nd part }/{3rd part }/{ page URL }/{ querystring param}

So if I manually change page URL part like `p2348` to `p1234`, website will redirect to the proper page:

> http://www.somesite.com/kids/clothing/padded-down-jackets/khuno-kids-padded-jacket-p1234.aspx?cl=BLUE

I don't know how to do that. Please help with regular expression to match those 4 digit while p remains there OR help me with those three parts matching any text/number and then 4 digit product code.

Comment: What have you tried, how did it fail, and why do you think a regex is the way to solve your problem (which after two readings I still don't understand)?

Comment: i have tried this to match 
[^p]\d[0-9][0-9]  p1234 in url

Comment: Ok can you help me with regex which matches starting character p followed by any 4 numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
p[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.aspx
```

if there are always 4 digits after the p.

Your attempt

```
 [^p]\d[0-9][0-9]
```

does not work because `[^p]` matches anything except for p, and `\d[0-9][0-9]` matches only three digits instead of four.

Comment: thats perfect...this is one way. what if i want to match www.somesite.com/match1/match2/match3/sometext-p1234.aspx

Comment: Did you try? No changes necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this regex. It's the most simple one and functional as well.

```
p\d{4}
```

This will return you strings like `p7634`, `p7351`, `p0872`.

If you are not completely sure there will be exactly 4 digits, use the following regex.

```
p\d*
```

This one will return you strings like `p43`, `p9165`, `p012`, `p456897689` and others.